# Spark Memsql connector do not work

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, singlestore

i create a simple flow

```
 val streamFromFirstTopic = spark
      .read
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", s"$kafkaHost:9092")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("subscribe",topicNamefirst)

      .fromConfluentAvro("value", None, Some(createschemaRegistryConfs(schemaRegistryURL,topicNamefirst,valueRestResponseSchema)))(RETAIN_SELECTED_COLUMN_ONLY) // invoke the library passing over parameters to access the Schema Registry
      .toDF()


    streamFromFirstTopic
      .write
      .format("console")
      .save()
```

its work ok. and so data as needed. 
when i try to add code below

```
streamFromFirstTopic
                       .write
      .format("com.memsql.spark.connector")
      .mode("error")
      .option("insertBatchSize",100)
      .save("test.test2")
```

Memsql is only create table but not save this data . also in logs i saw that data  uploads from kafka but do not save in memsql. and i do not see any errors.
Where it can be a problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "Memsql is only create data but not save this data"?  Do you see any activity in the Spark SQL UI?  It may be easier to diagnose your issue at MemSQL public chat: http://chat.memsql.com

Comment: hi. find that memsql connectors works ok. but i do like how spark  sql batchs work. Maybe you can send some like of example of integration spark from kafka to memsql ??

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading data to Database using below code:

```
     streamFromFirstTopic.write
    .format("singlestore")
    .option("loadDataCompression", "LZ4")
    .option("insertBatchSize",100)
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .save("test.test2") // in format: database.table
```

You can also go thru the kafka-singlestore configuration settings on Singlestore's official [documentation](https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.8/en/load-data/load-data-from-a-data-source/load-data-from-kafka/load-data-from-the-confluent-kafka-connector.html)